# Doing MySQL queries increasing each time number of columns retrieved

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to MySQL, I have only worked with NoSQL databases before.

I have to test MySQL performance, by querying a table, every time increasing complexity of the query.

For instance, table is comprised of these columns:

```
Timestamp, A922, A923, A924, ... , A933
```

`Timestamp` is a `DATETIME` type, the others are `INT`.

How can I do in Java to make a query like this without writing every query but using instead a loop?

```
SELECT Timestamp, A922 FROM Table 
SELECT Timestamp, A922, A923 FROM Table 
SELECT Timestamp, A922, A923, A924 FROM Table
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `SELECT Timestamp, A922 FROM Table1`? The SQL you're asking for doesn't make sense when `Timestamp` and `A922` are fields...?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I'll edit question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
String query = "SELECT Timestamp";
for (int i = 922; i <= 933; i++) {
    query += ", A" + i;
    //Execute the query as (query + " FROM Table") and analyze
}
```

Comment: sorry, I was wrong on writing the question, I meant something like `SELECT Timestamp, A922 FROM Table`

Comment: One question, do I attach at the end of `query` string `"FROM TABLE"` for each loop?

Comment: No. Not sure what the exact Java syntax is, but for example if the function that executes queries is execSQL(), you would do execSQL(query + " FROM Table"). This would not concatenate the from clause to the query string but would only add it to the string that the function receives.